# Database migrations with Strapi

Tags: mysql, database, integration, strapi, knex.js

As you know, a database migration process is necessary for each deployment of a new version that modifies the database schema. I am new to Strapi, and my question is concerning this point.

Knowing that this modification is always done in a visual way from the Strapi admin dashboard (for example by adding a collection or a link between two collections: which generates the creation of a tables at the database level). I imagine it’s faster, easier, and more secure to let the core of Strapi create this **db migration file** automatically for us. But I don’t know if this already implemented in Strapi.

Is this currently possible via some Strapi configuration setup. Or should we implement this file (as suggested by [this page](https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/database-migrations)) which could be quite complicated?

If the single way to have database migration files is by writing them from scratch, could you please share your best practice or tricks for that ? For my part I can imagine versioning the schema of the db in sql, before and after the modification and making a comparison of the two files to know what was modified and subsequently implementing it in Knex…

In short, how, guys, are you doing to manage the migration of the db with each new version of the strapi-backend that affects the schema of the db?

(I am using MySql for the DB)

THANKS